# Resizeing an Array

Tags: java, processing

If I have declared of an array **(ex. int a[5])** is there any method by which I could change the length of **a[ ]** (**say to 3**)? ie, I need the value of the **a.length** to be decreased to 50.

Please tell me the solution in any language which I have tagged.

I would also like to as one more part.
if the array **a[ ]** is created **dynamically** and I have entered **100** elements to it. Later I need to modify the **same array**, by deleteing the last 50 elements. Now the array should have only 50 elements and the code **a.length** should return value 50. How can I achieve this?
**NOTE:** I do not want to use a third variable or copy the contents to another array. This is to avoid wasting of memory.

Comment: I would suggest you to go for collections class in java

Comment: There is no safe way to re-size an array in C++. You would need a user defined type such as an `std::vector`. This can be used as an array, but it isn't one.

Comment: as an example say a[]={10,5,6,8,7};
                  a.length; // gives 5
            i need the array tobe modified as
                 a[]={10,5,6};
           and
                a.length;  //should return 3

Comment: @MELWIN That's what `std::vector` is for in C++.

Comment: Just pass once through your input data without storing elements. Just count the elements instead. Then, allocate an array of the exact amount of elements and read the data again. This is -the- way no to waste memory, although you'll require 2 passes through the input instead of one.

Comment: Java, C++ or Processing? Pick one.

Comment: HEY ALL OF U if u dont know the answer why voteing down? I asked my doubt only. to whom all have voted down please let me know why you did it. I am new to STACKOVERFLOW. your reply would help me to not reduce my reputation. so please

Comment: I didn't downvote, but the two languages are very different, lists for java or vectors for C++. The answer to varying the size after also depends on the language. This would be better as two questions with some sample code demonstrating what you do understand

Comment: @Joni i have selected the 3 tags because i need to know if there is any method available. Actually i need the answer in PROCESSING. but i havent received any answer when i tag it alone.

Comment: @doctorlove Ok now I have removed c++. But i keep the tag java and processing as almost everything written in java is supportable in processing too.

Comment: @v.k. Sorry which post please... I have no problem of down vote. But sad no one is able to help on what i need.

Comment: Ops, I got confused sorry

Comment: You might like those: [Why_use_ArrayList_instead_of_array_with_append()](http://wiki.processing.org/w/Why_use_ArrayList_instead_of_array_with_append()%3F)   -  [append()](http://processing.org/reference/append_.html)  -  [shorten()](http://processing.org/reference/shorten_.html)  -  [expand()](http://processing.org/reference/expand_.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably understand from the other answers that it is not possible to change the size of an array after you create it. When you say

```
int [] A = new int[5];
```

what you are really saying is that you have an object called 'A' and you want to put in there an array of integers and size 5. You can not change that array. You can though put in 'A' a new array of integers and size 3 just by saying:

```
A = new int[3];
```

If you do that (provided you don't have other references to it) the old array will be thrown away by the garbage collector. You just need to copy whatever you had in that old array to the new one and you are done! This will also change the length.

Here's a little test code:

```
int [] a = new int[5];
a[0] = 2;
a[1] = 5;
a[2] = 1;
a[3] = 6;
a[4] = 0;
println(a.length); // prints 5
int [] temp = new int[3];
System.arraycopy(a,0,temp,0,temp.length);
a = temp;
temp = null;
println(a.length); //prints 3
```

This is considered an ugly approach because you can do this much more elegantly using an ArrayList, which can be resized directly;

Technically this is copying the array into a new array, but it might be what you are looking for

Comment: I accept it. but its not what i needed. Since we use temporary variable. I accept it that the size cant be changed. THANK YOU

Comment: In general you would probably get better answers (and happier answerers) if you told us why you have these restrictions! If it's just to avoid wasting memory, you should heed to the advice given here. Unless you are handling datasets of gigabytes, (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18635124/resizeing-an-array/18635162#18635162), or are deploying on a really limited device, you are better off using ArrayLists, at least to make your code simpler and maintanable.

Comment: Petros Koutsolampros: :)

Answer (score 1):

C++: Use `vector`. It has resize function.

Answer (score 0):

In Java you can use `List` instead, particularly `ArrayList`.

You can also check the [Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) utility.

Comment: ArrayList is the "resizeable-array implementation of List interface" as documented here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the size of an array, but you can create a new bigger array and copy the old array into it. If you don't want to copy contents, then create a big enough array in the first place.

If you intend to modify the array a lot, you're better off using a class from the `Collections` framework. For raw bytes an array or a `ByteBuffer` would be more suitable (but even `ByteBuffer` can't be resized dynamically).

Also, is memory an issue here? How much data are we talking about? 1GB? 2GB? 10GB?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about other languages,  but in JAVA, you can't change the `array` size. The only option is to crate a new array of smaller/larger size and copy the contents appropriately. This is the same logic used by `ArrayList` to dynamically increase its size. There are different factors influencing how arraylist grows, so looking into the source code can give you more insight.

Comment: Will someone say is it available in PROCESSING please.
thank you

Comment: What do u mean by " is it available in PROCESSING " ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to increase/reduce the memory allocated for an array in java/c++.
If you need a container with varying size, you should be using a list container. If you don't want to use a container you'll have to reallocate new memory every time you need to change the size of your array

Comment: -1 Vector container is appropriate replacement, not list.

Comment: @NeilKirk Java's list?

Comment: @Eng.Fouad He said C++/Java, not just Java.

Comment: @NeilKirk Even in c++, I would argue a list has its merits over a vector if you're going to resize your container all the time. That's why I referred to the java List interface which is implemented by both ArrayList (array backed list container, equivalent to c++ vector) and LinkedList. I consider both a linked list and an array backed list to be viable choices here.

Comment: The OP asks for resizable array. Without any more info on what he is doing, we have to assume he wants an array which allows random index. List does not allow random index so it is not an equivalent replacement. In C++ resizing a vector of basic data types is often faster than resizing a list. I don't know what an array backed list container is, but a vector stores its data is a single contiguous array of memory.